# Unlock login keychain on sierra via ssh

Tags: ssh, keychain, macos-sierra

I am trying to unlock login keychain while I am connected to mac via ssh on Sierra. El Capitan works without any problem.

When I connect to mac and list keychains I get this result:

```
security list-keychains
"/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
"/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

But when I do the same command on the El Capitan:

```
"/Users/hudson/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
"/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

I found out when I connect through certificate I can see login keychain, but I can't even unlock it. Any ideas?

thank you

Comment: You should probably [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into the same issue when upgrading a build machine from El Capitan to Sierra.  I found that to gain back the ability to manipulate the login keychain, that it was required to sign into SSH using the key-based authentication.  When signed in using an authorized key, I was able to see the login.keychain again.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, unfortunatly setuping a ssh key-based auth did not fix my issue. Has anyone found another solution to this problem ?